# Is it possible to create a window on top of a right-click menu?

Tags: java, windows, swing, contextmenu

What I want to achieve is this:

On Windows platform:

1. Right click on a window  (some context menu will show up)
2. Capture the screenshot into a bitmap.
3. Create a window containing the screenshot **on top of everything** in the screen, **including the context window**.

Is step 3 possible?

### ADD 1

I am going through the Window Styles from the 2 links below:

[Extended Windows Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543(v=vs.85).aspx)

[Windows Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx)

Not sure if they can help me.

Comment: Don't see what would stop you.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I guess it should be possible. But I don't know how to do that. Any specific Win32 API? I have made some attempt. But my Swing window cannot overlay on top of the context menu on Windows desktop, which means it cannot `intercept` the input focus before the context menu.

Comment: Try `Robot#createScreenCapture()`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3742841/230513).

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a solution in C# that may be applicable. If you bring the window to the front *after* the context menu has been created, it will bring it in front of the context menu. You can emulate a window that is always on top of everything on the screen by repeatedly bringing it to the front in a background thread.

Here is the C# implementation:

[How to draw on top of the right-click menu in .NET/C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37395368/how-to-draw-on-top-of-the-right-click-menu-in-net-c)

This link may also help. I don't know if the same process could be used to display on top of the right-click menu, especially not in Java, but it may be worth a look:

[How can I make my own application on top in the start menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629406/how-can-i-make-my-own-application-on-top-in-the-start-menu)